# Unit testing in Android Studio gives an error

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

I am trying to write a unit test for my class, but I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method isEmpty in android.text.TextUtils not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

at android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(TextUtils.java)
at com.mvvm.testmvvm.Model.User.isValidUser(User.java:37)
at com.mvvm.testmvvm.LoginViewModelTest.isValidUser_Test(LoginViewModelTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

this is my class

```
public class User {

    private String  mEmail;
    private String  mPassword;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String mEmail, String mPassword) {
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
        this.mPassword = mPassword;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setEmail(String mEmail) {
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String mPassword) {
        this.mPassword = mPassword;
    }

    public int isValidUser () {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getEmail()) == true)
            return 0;
        else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(getEmail()).matches())
            return 1;
        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getPassword()) == true)
            return 2;
        else if (getPassword().length() < 6)
            return 3;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

and this is my test class

```
public class LoginViewModelTest {

    @Test
    public void isValidUser_Test() {

        User user = new User("a.elsayed2010@gmail.com", "amira123");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

**EDIT**

```
@Test
    public void isValidUser_happyCase() {

        User user = new User("a.elsayed2010@gmail.com", "amira123");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(-1, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void isValidUser_emptyEmail() {

        User user = new User("", "amira123");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void isValidUser_invalidEmail() {

        User user = new User("aaaaaaa", "amira123");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void isValidUser_emptyPassword() {

        User user = new User("a.elsayed2010@gmail.com", "");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(2, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void isValidUser_invalidPassword() {

        User user = new User("a.elsayed2010@gmail.com", "111");
        int result = user.isValidUser();
        assertEquals(3, result);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use classes specific to the Android framework within local JUnit tests (e.g. `TextUtils` in your case), they are only present as stubs if you enable `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true`. From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html):

> If you run a test that calls an API from the Android SDK that you do not mock, you'll receive an error that says this method is not mocked. That's because the `android.jar` file used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code (those APIs are provided only by the Android system image on a device).

You've got three options:

- First is to use the [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) testing library, which provides functional versions of Android classes for running in local JUnit tests. This would only need the addition of `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` at the top of your test.
- Second is to instead run your tests as [Instrumented Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) by placing your test classes under the `src/andoidTest` folder and running the tests on an actual device or emulator.
- One last option is to create your own null-safe utility method, as `String.isEmpty()` can throw a `NullPointerException` and the Apache `StringUtils` library is not natively available to Android:

---

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable String in) {
    return in == null || in.isEmpty();
}
```

I'd advise the first option as you're only using a utility class.

Comment: Ok I will try the first option and get back to you